# How to get the Row index and Columns index in the datagridView

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

My question is: When I click some Checkbox, how can I get the current checkbox control's index from DataGridView
Here is my snick code

```
dataGridView2.RowCount = 5;
    dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.RowCount; j++)
        {
            box = new CheckBox();
            box.Text = "MyDate";
            //box.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 15);
            dataGridView2.Controls.Add(box);
            Rectangle rec = dataGridView2.GetCellDisplayRectangle(i, j, true);
            box.Left = rec.Left;
            box.Top = rec.Top;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you try adding pure `CheckBox`es to your `DataGridView` without using a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`, the solution for this approach is simple like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.RowCount; j++)
        {
            box = new CheckBox();
            box.Text = "MyDate";
            //box.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 15);
            dataGridView2.Controls.Add(box);
            Rectangle rec = dataGridView2.GetCellDisplayRectangle(i, j, true);
            box.Left = rec.Left;
            box.Top = rec.Top;
            //Added code
            box.Tag = new Point(i,j);
            box.Click += CheckBoxesClicked;
        }
    }
private void CheckBoxesClicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
   CheckBox chb = sender as CheckBox;
   if(chb.Tag != null) {
      Point coord = (Point)chb.Tag;
      MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Row index: {0}\nColumn index: {1}", coord.Y, coord.X);
   }
}
```

You should use a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` instead, with that approach, you can handle the event `CellContentClick`...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the `CellContentClick` event or any other event that you get the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` then you have `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` properties that are the column and row of the cell changed

Answer (score 0):

Check this links. This gives you details about grid view.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972814.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479344.aspx